Do I need to follow the "OAuth2 authorization code flow" when using Keycloak login page?
I am new to Keycloak and I have a task to integrate it into our web applications in order to add authentication using the built in Keycloak login page.
I am trying to figure out what should be the flow from the moment the user trying to access my web application till he access the required page (after a successful login)
I did a small demo with Keycloak. Created a user and an OpenIdConnect client, set the "Valid redirect URIs" and "Web origins" of the my web application.
To test the login page with a redirect to my web application, I used the link below:
http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=myclientOpenIdConnect&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMyWebApp%2F&response_mode=query&response_type=code
The result is:
I get into the login page, enter valid credentials, I am redirected to the page I set in the redirect uri which is what I have expected.
If I try to use the login url again I am immediately redirected to the page I wanted, skipping the login page which is what I have expected.
I am guessing Keycloak is creating a cookie(or another mechanism) which helps it understanding that I am already authenticated.
Our current goal is to secure only the frontend. Meaning to force the web application user to login, before he can access the content.
Do I still need to follow the "OAuth2 authorization code flow" or is it enough that Keycloak validated the credentials and created the session?
What is the recommended flow when using Keycloak for authentication?
thanks
